# Two definitions of universal hash functions

Tags: probability-theory, hash, hashing

I have seen two definitions of universal hash functions in the literature.

For any $i \geqslant 2$ let $[i]=\{1,\ldots,i\}$.

Definition 1:

> A family $\mathcal H$
>   of hash functions from $[n]$ to $[m]$ is a
>   *$k$-universal family of hash functions* if for any distinct $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in[n]$ and any possibly identical
>   $v_1,\ldots,v_k\in[m]$, $$ \Pr\limits_{h\in\mathcal H} [h(x_1)=v_1\wedge \cdots \wedge h(x_k) = v_k] \leqslant 1/m^k \enspace . $$

Definition 2:

> A family $\mathcal H$
>   of hash functions from $[n]$ to $[m]$ is a
>   *$k$-universal family of hash functions* if for any distinct $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in[n]$, $$ \Pr\limits_{h\in\mathcal H} [h(x_1)=\cdots=h(x_k) ] \leqslant 1/m^{k-1} \enspace . $$

In both definitions if equality holds then it is called strongly $k$-universal or alternatively $k$-wise independent hash family.

Clearly the first definition implies the second. But is the other direction true?

It is easy to see that this is not the case for $n\leqslant m$.

> This is a counter example when $[n]\subseteq [m]$:
>
> Consider the family $\mathcal H$ composed of only one element, the
>   identity function: $x \mapsto x$. It satisfies the second definition
>   since for all $x \neq y \in [n], \Pr_{h\in\mathcal H} [h(x) = h(y)] = 0 \leqslant 1/m^{k-1}$. However, it does not satisfy the first definition
>   since for all $x,y\in[n], \Pr_{h\in\mathcal H}[h(x) = x \wedge h(y) = y] = 1 > 1/m^k$.
>
> This answer is inspired by this [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/367119/558).

However, hash functions are usually employed in applications where $n>m$. So my question is whether this is also the case for $n>m$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two definitions are not equivalent.  The second definition does not imply the first.  You can take $\mathcal{H}$ to be the collection of all functions $h$ such that $h(1) = 1$.